# How do I pivot this data on a bit field in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm working in SQL Server 2008, and have a unity table with a bit field to indicate if a person is a "Payee" or a "SubPayee". I need to join this data to another query that returns payment information, and the only way that I've been able to get the required output is by applying two subqueries to the select statement. Right now I'm working with a small amount of data, but anticipate that the subqueried table (`PaymentPayee`) will be massive. So I want to make this efficient up front.

My thought is to pivot the data into a table variable before joining it, and then just join on a `PaymentID` from my table variable.

Here is the subquery that I'm working with right now, which I would like to pivot.

```
SELECT  pp.PaymentID,
        p.PayableTo,
        pp.IsSubPayee
FROM    Payee p
        INNER JOIN PaymentPayee pp ON p.PayeeID = pp.PayeeID
```

This produces the following output:

```
PaymentID   PayableTo      IsSubPayee
1001        Bill Jones     0
1001        John Smith     1
1002        John Smith     0
1002        Jim Thorson    1
```

I would like to pivot the above into the following:

```
PaymentID   PrimaryPayee   SubPayee
1001        Bill Jones     John Smith
1002        John Smith     Jim Thorson
```

I've looked at several pivot examples online, and have been unable to figure this one out. My original query with the sub-queries looks something like this.

```
SELECT  p.*,
        p1.PayableTo AS PrimaryPayee,
        p2.PayableTo AS SubPayee
FROM    dbo.Payment p
        INNER JOIN dbo.PaymentDetail pd ON p.PaymentID = pd.PaymentID
        INNER JOIN dbo.Loan l ON p.LoanID = l.LoanID
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT  Payee.PayableTo,
                    pp.PaymentID
            FROM    dbo.Payee
                    INNER JOIN dbo.PaymentPayee pp ON Payee.PayeeID = pp.PayeeID
            WHERE   (pp.IsSubPayee = 0)
            ) p1 ON p.PaymentID = p1.PaymentID
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT  Payee.PayableTo,
                    pp.PaymentID
            FROM    dbo.Payee
                    INNER JOIN dbo.PaymentPayee pp ON Payee.PayeeID = pp.PayeeID
            WHERE   (pp.IsSubPayee = 1)
            ) p2 ON p.PaymentID = p2.PaymentID
```

This was my original attempt at pivoting the data, but I realize this is wrong.

```
SELECT  PaymentID, PayableTo, IsSubPayee
FROM    (
        SELECT  pp.PaymentID,
                p.PayableTo,
                pp.IsSubPayee
        FROM    Payee p
                INNER JOIN PaymentPayee pp ON p.PayeeID = pp.PayeeID
        ) x
PIVOT   (
        MAX(PaymentID)
        FOR IsSubPayee IN (0, 1)
        ) piv
```

How can I pivot those payees and produce the output of having `PaymentID`, `PrimaryPayee`, and `SubPayee`? Thanks for your help.

=== Edit 5/5/2015 at 8:28 AM ===

Thanks Tab. So I've adjusted the query this way, which seems closer to the mark, but I'm having difficulty with the query inside the PIVOT statement.  Here is what I have.

```
SELECT  PaymentID, PrimaryPayee, SubPayee
FROM    (
        SELECT  pp.PaymentID,
                CASE WHEN pp.IsSubPayee = 0 THEN p.PayableTo ELSE NULL END PrimaryPayee,
                CASE WHEN pp.IsSubPayee = 1 THEN p.PayableTo ELSE NULL END SubPayee
        FROM    Payee p
                INNER JOIN PaymentPayee pp ON p.PayeeID = pp.PayeeID
        ) x
PIVOT   (
        MAX(PaymentID) AS PaymentID
        FOR IsSubPayee IN (0, 1)
        ) piv
```

That subquery inside the FROM produces this output.

```
PaymentID    PrimaryPayee    SubPayee
1001         Bill Jones      NULL
1001         NULL            John Smith
1002         John Smith      NULL
1002         NULL            Jim Thorson
```

Now I just need to collapse those results into 2 rows.

Comment: Pivot on a CASE statement that returns either "PrimaryPayee" or "SubPayee"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *conditional aggregates* to obtain the required result:

```
SELECT PaymentID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN IsSubPayee = 0 THEN PayableTo END) AS PrimaryPayee,
       MAX(CASE WHEN IsSubPayee = 1 THEN PayableTo END) AS SubPayee
FROM (SELECT  pp.PaymentID, p.PayableTo, pp.IsSubPayee
      FROM Payee p
      INNER JOIN PaymentPayee pp ON p.PayeeID = pp.PayeeID) t
GROUP BY PaymentID
```

If you like to use `PIVOT` then use the following query:

```
SELECT PaymentID, [0] AS PrimaryPayee, [1] AS SubPayee
FROM 
   (SELECT  pp.PaymentID, p.PayableTo, pp.IsSubPayee
    FROM Payee p
    INNER JOIN PaymentPayee pp ON p.PayeeID = pp.PayeeID) p
PIVOT
(
   MAX (PayableTo)
   FOR IsSubPayee IN ( [0], [1] )
) AS pvt
```

Comment: You're welcome. You can have a look at the edit I made. Column being aggregated by `PIVOT` is `PayableTo`, not `PaymentID`.

Comment: Thanks so much. Will one traditionally perform better than the other?  The execution plan looks the same.  The conditional aggregate appears more readable.

Comment: `PIVOT` is just syntactic sugar for conditional aggregates. You can use whichever you feel more comfortable with.